# After push, git says everything up to date but changes are not in the repo

Tags: git, github, git-push

I'm pretty new to using Git, so maybe I'm doing something basic wrong. What I'm trying to do is push the commits of a branch to the remote repo on Github. I tried the following line

```
git push origin Interface
```

It returns 'Everything up-to-date', but when I check the branch on Github, my changes aren't there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to double-check: you did first commit your changes to the Interface branch?

Comment: Run `git status` to view any uncommited changes. Run `git log` to see your local log - compare this to the branch on GitHub.

Comment: turns out I commited stuff on master, not on the branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you push make sure that files are added to the index and changes have been committed. Its a good practice to commit with a message. In case you did not commit with message, use `git log` to find SHA for most recent commit. On the Git-hub check the SHA or message for most recent commit.

While doing `git push <remote> <local_branch>:<remote_branch>` make sure that you are uploading changes to correct remote and branch.

On the Git-hub verify that you are on the correct branch and revision.